# iterating through list : error lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

I am trying to solve this error, but failed miserably. I have declared my code below

```
msc_con_list_slot msc_slot;
memset(&msc_slot, 0, sizeof(msc_slot));
msc_pdn_con_t*conn = &msc_slot.conn;

msc_ber_list_slot bearer_slot;
memset(&bearer_slot, 0, sizeof(bearer_slot));
msc_ber_t *bearer = &bearer_slot.bearer;
```

and tried to iterate it

```
for(&bearer_slot=(&(conn->bearers))->head; &bearer_slot; &bearer_slot=(&bearer_slot)->next)
{
//asign value here 
}
```

I got an error of : 
lvalue required as left operand of assignment 
warning: the address of ‘bearer_slot’ will always evaluate as ‘true’

Maybe I miss something, because I don't really get what is the error actually mean is. Thank you for your help

edit add struct:

```
typedef struct {
        int id;
} msc_ber_t;

typedef struct _msc_ber_list_slot {
        msc_ber_t bearer;
        struct _msc_ber_list_slot *next, *prev;
} msc_ber_list_slot;

typedef struct {
        msc_ber_list_slot *head, *tail;
} msc_ber_list;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the for loop, you are assigning values to `&bearer_slot`, that is, the address of the variable `bearer_slot`, which is not allowed (it is not an `lvalue`) and makes no sense.  Furthermore, your loop condition is the value of `&bearer_slot`, which will always evaluate to `true` (as it is a non-`NULL` pointer), so your loop will run forever.  You will need to provide more context on what you want this loop to do.  By the way, `(&x)->y` can be written more succinctly as `x.y` - this would make your code a lot more readable.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, but I still can not get the sentence of  "the address of the variable bearer_slot, which is not allowed (it is not an lvalue) and makes no sense"  @James

Comment: `bearer_slot` is a variable.  You set its value using `bearer_slot = whatever`.  `&bearer_slot` gives you a _pointer_ that tells you where `bearer_slot` is stored in the memory.  It makes no sense to change this representation of the physical location of the variable to another value.  In technical terms, `&bearer_slot` is an `rvalue`, not an `lvalue` - that is, you cannot set its value.  Compare with the statement `x+1=y;` (where `x` and `y` are, say, ints) - this is not allowed as `x+1` is an `rvalue`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this:

```
&bearer_slot=(&(conn->bearers))->head;
```

Show us how `msc_ber_list_slot` is defined.

I imagine you want something ***like*** this:

```
struct msc_ber_list_slot *slot;
for(slot=conn->bearers.head; slot; slot=slot->next)
{
//asign value here 
}
```

Comment: why I can't do it? I edit the struct, also tried your suggestion but it return me different error of invalid type argument of ‘->’  (have ‘msc_ber_list’)
  @cnicutar

Comment: @heike How is `msc_pdn_con_t` defined ?